# How call my javascript library from Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

how can I use my javascript lib in Angular.

My javascript file is like this: `eletronic-prescription.js`

```
function EletronicPrescriptionReport(data) {

    var wrapper;
    var medicineIndex;
    var itemsPerPage = 3;
    var prescriptionDate;

    this.preview = function () {
        preparePDFReport(function () {
            wrapper = new ReportWrapper('p', 'mm', data, false);
            var output = generateReport();
            showPDF(output, "Prescrição");
        });
    }
   ....
```

Normally, in old project I used this way:

```
var report = new EletronicPrescriptionReport(response);
report.preview();
```

In Angular, I'm trying to use same way but get error

> `EletronicPrescriptionReport is not a constructor`

```
import { EletronicPrescriptionReport } from 'assets/scripts/reports/eletronic-prescription'
...
var report = new EletronicPrescriptionReport(data);
report.preview();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this value to `angular.json`:

```
"scripts": ["assets/scripts/reports/eletronic-prescription.js"]
```

Or add an import script line in your `index.html`:

```
<script src="/assets/scripts/reports/eletronic-prescription.js"></script>
```